# Change time in asterisk 11

Tags: time, asterisk

I want to add a minute for a call file.

I use this for time:

```
Set(starttime=${STRFTIME(${EPOCH},,%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S)});
```

**result:**
2014-04-10 13:52:50

**want this result:**
2014-04-10 13:53:50

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this:

```
Set(starttime=${STRFTIME($[ ${EPOCH} + 60 ],,%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S)});
```

Have work becuase of:

> ${EPOCH}: The current UNIX-style epoch (number of seconds since 1 Jan
>   1970)